# With LINQ, get count of items that satisfy criteria in grouping

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm probably going to butcher the terminology if I try too hard, so it'll be easier to describe via code:

`var fooGroup = fooList.GroupBy(x => x.SomeID);

//fooGroup is now of type IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Foo>>

var someCount = fooGroup.Count(y => y.Where(f => f.Bar == "Bar"));`

The above will not compile due to this error: "Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type `System.Func<System.Linq.IGrouping<int,Foo>,bool>` 
because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type"

I assume the answer is pretty easy, but I can't quite wrap my head around how to do this.

Comment: You should explain at a high level what you are trying to accomplish.  e.g., "I want to count how many foos have a certain ID."  It's hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're trying to do with a group by does not make a whole lot of sense.  I propose the following.

If you're looking for how many elements have `Bar == "Bar"`, then do it before the group.

```
var someCount = fooList.Count(y => f.Bar == "Bar");
```

If you're looking to count the groups which contain an element which matches the same criteria.

```
var fooGroup = fooList.GroupBy(x => x.SomeID)
    .Where(x => x.Any(z => z.Bar == "Bar")).Count();
```

Comment: Everyone syntactically had good answers, but Jeffery is the one that made me dig my head out of the sand and re-think the big picture.  The way the code is setup did not make sense, and after I did the counting before the group, I got what I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Foo>>` you get by grouping.

It is an `IEnumerable` of groups. The group has a key type of `int`, which is because you grouped by the int id column. The grouping contains an `IEnumerable` which contains the list of objects which all have this key. It is of type `Foo`.

Then it is a simple query. From the grouping you find those that have the wanted key (i.e. the int id), and then select the count from the groups `IEnumerable`.

```
var fooGrouping = fooList.GroupBy(x => x.SomeID);
var someCount = fooGrouping.Where(grp => grp.Key == someKey).Select(p=>p.Count());
```

Comment: Of course, I am assuming you actually need the grouping further down in code and you just need to get the count from it by id for some reason :)

Comment: Being older and wiser now, please use: `.GroupBy(x->x.Key).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)`, and select from that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var someCount = fooGroup.Sum(y => y.Where(f => f.Bar == "Bar").Count());
```

Or even more clean

```
var someCount = fooGroup.Sum(y => y.Count(f => f.Bar == "Bar"));
```